# Need help in getting sequential impulse method working

Tags: javascript, physics

i have made a very very simple physics system based on sequential impulse method - with single contacts only and no angular rotation at all. Contact points are calculated using separating axis theorem.

Unfortunatly with small gravity my test-simulation is stable, but with increasing gravity it gets more and more unstable. My player and my moving elevator just goes crazy...

The solver is basically the same as box2d, but without any angular rotation at all - so no need for clipped contact points.

It does the following:

- Integrating the external forces (gravity, player input)
- Calculating all contact points using SAT for each unique body pair.
- Solving movement iteratively by applying impulses so it just touches the surface (restitution is set to zero)
- Integrating the new velocity to get a new position
- Re-calculate contact distances
- Solving position errors iteratively by applying impulses to the position by using baumgarte stabilization method

All the solver code is nearly a port of box2d Box2D/Dynamics/b2ContactSolver.cpp.
Even the coefficients are set to the same values and the world uses meters as units.

Does someone know this stuff and could help me to learn this properly please?
Since months i am fighting with this kind of physics programming and has always issues :-(
Unfortunatly i dont have any algebra knowledge, even though i understand the most of it.

Here is the short code in a javascript environment:
http://jsbin.com/xoqiquxoyo/1/